# reload table data in swift3

Tags: json, swift3

My screen consist of add and delete buttons, if I clicked add button then it opens popup screen and I entered fields and clicked on save button on the popup screen then data is added, if I close the popup screen then the table is not reloaded. please check my code as shown below.

```
class EditTest: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var position = [AnyObject]()
    var company = [AnyObject]()
    var location = [AnyObject]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
loadJsonData()

}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return position.count
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! customCell

    cell.position.text = position[indexPath.row] as? String
    cell.company.text = company[indexPath.row] as? String
    cell.location.text = location[indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        PopupController
            .create(self)
            .customize(
                [
                    .animation(.slideUp),
                    .scrollable(false),
                    .backgroundStyle(.blackFilter(alpha: 0.7))
                ]
            )
            .didShowHandler { popup in
                print("showed popup!")
            }
            .didCloseHandler { _ in
                print("closed popup!")
            }
            .show(DeleteRow.instance())

    }

    @IBAction func newExp(_ sender: Any) {

        PopupController
            .create(self)
            .customize(
                [
                    .animation(.slideUp),
                    .scrollable(false),
                    .backgroundStyle(.blackFilter(alpha: 0.7))
                ]
            )
            .didShowHandler { popup in
                print("showed popup!")
            }
            .didCloseHandler { _ in
                print("closed popup!")
            }
           .show(AddRow.instance())

    }

  func loadJsonData() {

        let url = URL(string: "https://url..../id")

        var request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringCacheData,timeoutInterval: 10000)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            do {
                if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data!, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                    print(jsonData)
                    for item in jsonData {

                        if let pos = item["Position"] as? AnyObject{
                            self.position.append(pos)
                        }
                        if let comp = item["Company"] as? AnyObject{
                            self.company.append(comp)
                        }
                        if let location = item["Location"] as? AnyObject{
                            self.location.append(location)
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
            }.resume()

    }

}
```

In the above code, what changes I do to update table data when I close the popup.

```
func saveMethod(sender:UIButton){
        let paramaters = ["Id": id,
                          "Position": pos,
                          "Company": com,
                          "Location": loc] as [String : Any]

let url = URL(string: “https://———/save”)!
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramaters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            do {
                //create json object from data
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // now update UI on main thread

                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: “Row”, message:   "Created Successfully", preferredStyle: .alert)

                        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ -> Void in

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }

                        })

                        alert.addAction(OKAction)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true){}
                    }
                }

            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        task.resume()

}
```

Comment: Why `AnyObject`? JSON values are never *objects* (reference type) in Swift. And why are the arrays declared as `[AnyObject]`? The type seems to be `[String]`. You have to call `tableView.reloadData()` wherever you want to reload the table view

Comment: ok, these are strings but in my code what changes I do to update table data when closed the popup.

Comment: I don't know the `PopupController` API but probably you have to call `tableView.reloadData()` in `didCloseHandler`

Comment: I tried tableView.reloadData() in didCloseHandler also but not reload data.

Comment: Where is the code which adds or removes items to and from the three arrays? Without that code the table view doesn't change.

Comment: ok, I added save method code in AddRow class, check code.

Comment: But there is no code which changes the data source arrays. You have to update the data source arrays (preferable) or reload the data from the server before reloading the table view.